# How do I copy one colum to another new tables

Tags: mysql

Example my table structure

`current_db`

```
ID email           name  address    phone
---------------------------------------------
1  email@email.com John  My Address  123456789
2  email@email.net Peter My Address  123456721
```

`new_db`

```
ID email column1  column2 column3  column4
------------------------------------------
```

How do I copy only email address from `current_db` to `new_db`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I mis-understood... early for me.  You mentioned from one database to another, not table to table.

If the tables were actually kept in separate "databases", such as rebuilding, or porting to a new database from an old and you were restructuring tables....  You would have to prefocus to the new database and create your table from an insert of the column desired from database.table from another.

```
use New_db
create table x select email from Other_Db.YourTable
```

However, from re-reading and seeing the other answer, that's probably closer to what you want

```
insert into OneTable ( columnX, columnY, columnZ ) values select x, y, z from OtherTable where...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`INSERT … SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `new_db` ( `email` )
SELECT `email` FROM `current_db`
```